# How do I allow one molecule platform to fail testing?

Tags: ansible, molecule

During development of Ansible roles you may want to add support for a new platform. This process could require a big number of changes so is better to first enable this new platform and allow it to fail without changing the final result.

How can I do this with molecule?

Answer (score 0):

I would add that platform alone to a new molecule base scenario and would not play it on CI until the role is fully ready. Once this time has come, I would either re-integrate that platform to the different other scenarios that are launched on you CI or add this new scenario in the list to be tested.

I actually have a scenario for each platform (using mainly docker as driver). On a tool like travis-ci.org, it has proved to be much more efficient to launch 7 scenarios in parallel than a single scenario addressing 7 platforms.

Other than that, I don't know any config or workaround to allow a platform to fail in a multi-platform scenario.